# use git diff or git format-patch only to get the modified line ranges after the patch

Tags: git, diff, git-diff, format-patch

I'd like to be able to call `git diff [something] <commit0>..<commit1>` and get the filenames and line numbers in commit 1 that had been modified since commit 0.
Currently, if I have

```
# foo.txt
foo

bar
```

and change '\nbar\n' -> 'baz', I get

```
diff --git a/foo.txt b/foo.txt
index 29a4dcd7..28932e58 100644
--- a/foo.txt
+++ b/foo.txt
@@ -1,5 +1,4 @@
 # foo.txt
 foo
-
-bar
+baz
```

How do I instruct git diff to isolate that line 2 (1-indexed) of the new version of `foo.txt` was modified? Is it possible without jumping into scripting languages?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for exactly.  Do you really want `1,4`, as that's not really telling you anything by itself.  You'd really need either `-1,5 +1,4` or some other interpretation of that data...?

Comment: I do want `('foo.txt', (1,4),)`.  Given I'm sitting at the end of a range of commits, I want to know what lines changed in the current state of the tracked files.

Comment: Right, but `1,4` by itself isn't telling you anything at all about what lines changed, is why I'm asking.  You need the leading `+` to even understand that this is a _postimage_ instruction (containing 4 lines of postimage, starting at line 1).  And that's _also_ useless without the `-1,5` _preimage_ instruction ahead of it (indicating that there are 5 lines of preimage, starting at line 1.  And then even with those two pieces of information all you know is that one line was removed, not _which_ line was removed.

Comment: (By the way, you've removed the last line from your patch and it won't apply - your header `-1,5` says that you have five preimage lines, but you only have four.  Similarly, your header `+1,4` says that you have four preimage lines, but in that case you only have three.  It appears that you've removed the trailing line which is shared context.)

Comment: (thanks, I'll fix that for clarity)

Comment: Got it! In that case, I'm looking for the after-image range meaning "just line 2" (1-indexed).  Unless this is a preexisting format, it's sounding like I'll need to use a scripting language to parse the chunk headers (`@@...@@`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188829/discussion-between-steven-kalt-and-edward-thomson).